# Where is Chrome Web Store 'Publish to Test Accounts' button? How to publish to testing?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I used to test my Chrome Apps by following these instructions:

https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/publish

Now, when I upload a new app for testing, the Publish to Test Accounts button is gone, and it seems to be replaced by a set of radio buttons, one of which is "Trusted Testers", and a single Publish button. When I publish that way, the app gets into a Pending Review state, and stays there (for over a day). It seems as though I've requested it be published for real, which I guess requires a review, but I only want to test it.

A month or so ago when I did this is became available for testing in minutes.

Has anyone successfully this week published an app for testing only?

UPDATE: To get along with my development, I took an app Published to Testers a few weeks ago, and updated it with a completely unrelated app that I'm working on now. It appeared as Published to Testers within a few minutes. So, I am able to reuse this "container" for testing various apps. But, I am unable to publish anything new to testers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be temporary. A day later, publishing became responsibe again, with a quick response.